# JavaFX wont load FXML, can't find resources

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to get my FXML files to load as UI elements from subfolders in this project structure:

```
InventoryManagementUI 
    InventoryManagementUI.Java

    Controller
        MainMenuController.Java
    View
        MainMenu.fxml
    Model
```

I'm having trouble getting the actual resources by location and have tried the following:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("View/MainMenu.fxml"));        
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/MainMenu.fxml"));       
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("inventorymanagementui/View/MainMenu.fxml"));
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/inventorymanagementui/View/MainMenu.fxml"));
```

Here is my error log specifically when I use ...getResource("/View/MainMenu.fxml"):

These attempts are made within the start method of my InventoryManagementUI.java file. Why am I not able to get a reference to the FXML

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at inventorymanagementui.InventoryManagementUI.start(InventoryManagementUI.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I attempt to load via full classpath (this should be the correct way) like so:

```
...getResource("/inventorymanagementui/View/MainMenu.fxml"));
```

I get the error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:file:...NetBeansProjects/InventoryManagementUI/dist/run2552658/InventoryManagementUI.jar!/inventorymanagementui/View/MainMenu.fxml:12

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at inventorymanagementui.InventoryManagementUI.start(InventoryManagementUI.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: inventorymanagementui.MainMenu.MainMenuController
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
... 17 more
```

Comment: This seems like a file path issue. Are you familiar with [relative vs absolute paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths)? I would suggest trying to use the absolute path of the file. If it still doesn't work, it probably means the problem is not the parameter to `getResource()`

Comment: Are you using any build tools (e.g. Maven or Gradle)?

Comment: I'm using default netbeans, I believe it builds to a JAR file. If you could point me in the direction to check whether I am using those I will gladly get back to you.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that when I refactored my code I forgot to change the fx:id declaration from the previous inventorymanagementui.MainMenu.MainMenuController to inventorymanagementui.Controller.MainMenuController